# I can't create a jar file. Error : Could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

I try to create a jar file with maven but the dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.streams</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-streams</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

make the error : Could not find artifact

I tried to insert a repositories

```
<repository>
            <id>apache-streams</id>
            <name>Apache Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/streams/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
</repository>
```

but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional repositories,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.streams</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-streams</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

is available in Maven central which is the default repositories so you don't have to configure it manually: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.streams/apache-streams/0.6.1

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/streams/apache-streams/0.6.1/

If the network connection was bad the first time you tried to access this artifact Maven will cache it and will use the cached error for some days instead. You can force Maven to forget the cached error by deleting the artifact folder in the Maven cache in your user profile/home folder:

Go to `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/streams/apache-streams/0.6.1/` and delete the contained files. Next time you execute Maven it will retry to download the artifact from al configured repositories.

Even if you want to configure a repository manually you have to configure the root path of the repository without the artifact name. Therefore the correct URL would be

```
Correct path:
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
```

Instead of what you used (which is the wrong path as it contains the artifact path):

```
wrong path:
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/streams/</url>
```

Comment: I tried to delete the contained files but the problem is always the same.